# Euler's theorem multiplicative inverse Z26

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Euler's theorem get the inverse of 2 in Z26...~
i tried to solve it but the result is not correct:
a=2,  φ (26) = 12, m=26
gcd(2,26)=21
multiplicative inverse of 2 = 1/2
2 * 1/2 = 1

gcd(2,26)=2

a^-1= a^11mod26=2^11mod26= 2046 mod 26= 20

a=2     a^-1=20
a*a^-1= 2*20=40

when doing the verification, 40 mod 26 = 14 not 1...

or for this group the Euler theorem is not applicable ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This would be easier to read if you used [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Euler's theorem assumes the base and modulus are relatively prime, but $\gcd(2,26)=2\ne1$

Comment: How did you get $\gcd(2,26)=21$ ? That's very wrong!

Comment: By the basic theorems in the linked dupes: $\,a\,$ is invertible $\!\bmod n\iff \gcd(a,n)= 1.\,$ If so, then Euler's theorem applies and can be used to compute the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

A nonzero element $a\in\Bbb Z_n$, $n\geq 2$, is invertible if and only if $gcd(a,n)=1$; otherwise $a$ is a zero divisor.

In your case $gcd(2,26)=2$ and so $2$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

> for this group the Euler theorem is not applicable ?

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) assumes the base and modulus are relatively prime, but that is not the case here:

$\gcd(2,26)=2\ne1$.

Answer (score 1):

$2$ cannot have an inverse mod $26$ because $13 \cdot 2 \equiv 0$.

Indeed, if $2a \equiv 1$, then $ 0 = 13 \cdot 2 a \equiv 13$, but $13 \not\equiv 0$.